# Prove that $A$ and $B$ are proportional

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

> Let $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices. Also, $$|\operatorname{tr}(A^TB) \,|^2 = \operatorname{tr}(A^TA) \, \operatorname{tr}(B^TB)$$ Prove that $A$ and $B$ are proportional.

I don't know with what I can start in this problem. Thank you!

Comment: The $\operatorname{tr} (A^T B)$ can be seen as an inner product on the space of matrices and Cauchy Schwartz's inequality gives gives that $\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)^2 \leq \operatorname{tr}(A^TA)\operatorname{tr}(B^TB)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are "colinear" that is proportional.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\langle A,B \rangle=tr(A^TB)$. It’s an inner product since $\langle A,A \rangle=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^2\geq 0$. So by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $|\langle A,B \rangle|=||A||||B||$ means $A,B$ are proportional.